# Should [session-state] and [session-variables] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I just answered a question on session state in PHP.  After I wrote my answer I went back to edit the details of the quest based on some of the OP's comments and to fix the tags.

I noticed two virtually identical tags, [session-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session-variables) and [session-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session-state).  I am pretty sure these need to be merged but wasn't sure exactly how to initiate the process.

I also noticed another tag [session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session) which is clearly not the same, but could be confusing as the description of [session-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session-state) goes on to say "commonly abbreviated as session".

So the actual question, then, is "should the [session-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session-state) and [session-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/session-variables) tags be merged?  And, if so - which should be retired?"